# Reset a userform to blank on button click

Tags: vba, excel

I have a dynamic `Userform`. When loaded only a `Combobox` is visible, and user selects one option and accordingly some `Labels` and `Textboxes` with values are populated. But when I choose another option from `Combobox` and click on the button, all labels disappears but `Textboxes` remains there. Is there any way to clear or reset the Userform completely before loading?

Comment: You can try [`Me.Repaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/repaint-method)?

Comment: not working.. tried repaint..but same effect

Comment: How about `DoEvents`? If it doesn't work, try combination of `Repaint` and `DoEvents`? Btw, I am assuming you have the routine to clear all the objects currently visible, is that correct?

Comment: yes, I need to clear all objects. Now what i did is I just made a button like refresh on clicking will unload the userform and load it again freshly..But it takes small time gap to load

Comment: Is that the same `Userform` where the refresh button is?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure how you set up your routines, I just based this answer on assumption.
 From what I understand, you want to reload the `Userform` using the same `CommandButton` in it. 
 If that is the case, you can try this:

- In a module, write a procedure that loads your form. Something like:

  ```
  Sub marine()
      Load Userform1
      Userform1.Show
  End Sub
  ```
- In your `CommandButton`, create a routine that will call the load procedure and at the same time unloads the form. Something like:

  ```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      '/* call the marine procedure after 0.5s */    
      Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 0.5, Now), "marine"
      Me.Hide
      Unload Me '/* unloads the userform    
  End Sub
  ```

Your `Userform` will be invisible momentarily (like it flickers) but it will be *reloaded* just like the way you want it to be. HTH.